# How do most graphic designers handle their branding mockups? Templates or DIY?

Tags: 3d, workflow, branding, stock-images, blender

I'm curious about how you handle your branding mockups for final delivery on a job. Putting logos or branding assets on 3D, real-world objects to demonstrate its use and final application, as well as to suggest the mood and tone of the brand.

Do you source these images from templates and stock websites? If so, which ones? Do you take your own photos or make your own mockup material libraries? If so, what is your process?

I'm particularly interested in some of these 3D modeled and rendered posters / fabrics that are trending in graphic design right now. In terms of complexity, it looks to me as though some of these styles can be achieved very simply in blender, on a beginner level, with just a few fabric physics, which is something that I would like to try myself but I'm struggling to find a decent tutorial close to what I'd want to achieve.

If you create your own 3D branding mockups in blender, are there any particular tutorials that you've found to be helpful?

Comment: You dont actually need fabric physics to mock up fabrics? Also fabric design is hardly graphic design is it. Its a part of fashon design. Wouldnt know though, i can manufacture the fabric in house so for me its just easier to make it...

Comment: Either a photo of the actual piece after production.. or a mock up I create myself. I don't use anything "canned" and BoxShot is as far into 3D as I go. (Would post this as answer but it's too short.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer for "most graphic designers", only for myself.  Graphic design is a very wide category, and different designers have their preferred workflow, software, and specialisms.

I make my own templates when I need one. I've never had to buy a pre-made template.  I usually either take a photo of the objects myself, or find a stock image from iStock, Adobe stock, or a Creative Commons image, then place the designs in Photoshop, convert them to Smart Objects, then Distort and Warp as necessary to position them on the objects.

I've dabbled in Blender, but wouldn't use it for this. I think Photoshop is enough for my needs. Of course other people may need or prefer Blender depending on what kind of work they do. Personally, I'm more into photography and image manipulation using raster image editors, and 2D graphic design such as vector image editing, with an emphasis on graphic design for print, or more specifically for offset lithography (which is my area of expertise). Any mockups I need are usually for things like leaflets, business cards, folders, etc. More often than not, I don't even need an actual mockup, since a flat PDF usually will suffice. Each to their own I suppose.

By the way, if you're looking for Blender Tutorials or advice, GDSE is probably isn't the best place. There's a dedicated [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)